# VBA code setup, compiler error: Syntax Error

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to develop a function for White's Test for Heteroskedasticity in Excel. I am just at the first stage, but I'm already stuck. I called the add-in regression method from data analysis. This will render the residuals needed for the auxiliary regression at the second stage. But I am getting `compiler error`, which is uninformative. What's wrong with the setup here?

```
Sub WhitesTest(Y As Range, X As Range)
    'This function will run the regression by default, but also report the White's Test for
    'heteroskedasticity

    Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Regress", Y, _
        X, False, False, , "", True, False, False _
        , False, , False
End Sub

Sub testWhitesTest()
    WhitesTest(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A6"),Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B6"))
End Sub
```

Comment: remove the parentheses from your call to `WhitesTest`  You'd only use parens if you're calling a function, or if using `Call WhitesTest()...`

Comment: Also, in the future, when you say "I'm getting compiler error", it helps drastically if you actually tell us what the compiler error message says. We can't see your screen from where we are (at least I can't). :-)

Comment: would [this](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/173086-multiple-linear-regression-visual-basic-applications.html) be any use?

Comment: @Ken White - I think he assumed you were omnipresent - like in that movie Jumper.

Comment: @Stepan1010: I sometimes am (like a lot of others here), but it's my week off. :-)

Comment: I am just stupid as hell.. You are right, I am writing a subroutine which is not a function..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is from @Tim Williams:

> remove the parentheses from your call to WhitesTest You'd only use
>   parens if you're calling a function, or if using Call WhitesTest()...